# failed to fetch IIS webAPI

Tags: iis, cors, fetch

I have a webPI running in localhost fine but when I publish it in IIS this request fails: http://planificador.fyseg.com/#/proyectos/X0000088/empleado/112/plan/horas
This same request in localhost works fine: http://localhost:5000/#/proyectos/X0000088/empleado/112/plan/horas

The error is this:

'http://planificadorwebapi.fyseg.com/api/proyectos/X0000088/fechainicio/2018-05-22T22:00:00.000Z/fechafin/2020-01-30T23:00:00.000Z/horas' from origin 'http://planificador.fyseg.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I have the webAPI configured like this
[image: startup.cs]

But at same time other requests to the same API from the same domain works, for exmaple
http://planificadorwebapi.fyseg.com/api/contratos/X0000088/mes/5/anio/2018/acumular/false

Any idea Please?

regards

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could check the plan horas method to make sure there is no special cros setting for this method.

If not,  I suggest you could try to add below setting in your IIS application's web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```